# asp.net EF core run command Scaffold-DbContext error foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mariadb

I use the mariaDB database in which the project I have installed the following package (via Nuget)

> - MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore (latest version)
> - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (latest version)

After that I used the commands below to create EF.

```
Scaffold-DbContext  "server=localhost;port=3306;user=root;password=mypass;database=test" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir DB -f
```

And found the error as follows

> Could not scaffold the foreign key 'test.payment_details(receipt_no)'.
>   A key for 'receipt_no' was not found in the principal entity type
>   'PaymentHeader'. Could not scaffold the foreign key
>   'test.payment_details(barcode)'. A key for 'barcode' was not found in
>   the principal entity type 'ProductPrice'. Could not scaffold the
>   foreign key 'test.promotion(premium_barcode)'. A key for 'barcode' was
>   not found in the principal entity type 'ProductPrice'.

Comment: I guess you didn't specify your EF relationships right. Which approach you using, model or code first?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can solve the problem. The method used is I changed from Key to Unique.